# How to Implement SIR Model in JAVA and Visualize it in Repast Simphony?

Tags: java, agent-based-modeling, repast-simphony

I've been given a Project to Code a SIR Model (Agent Based Modeling) from Scratch in JAVA and then Visualize the same through Repast Simphony using different Values of Beta and Gamma. I have setup Java, Eclipse and Repast Simphony but I don't know where and how to begin Coding the same.

Any help is Appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: It seems that you will find helpful the series starting with [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rSHcNpGOGOs).

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to look at [this paper](https://www.jasss.org/18/3/11.html) and the associated [project code](https://www.openabm.org/model/4466/version/1). This uses the statecharts capability in Repast Simphony to build an SEIR model.